# Difficulty with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm working on a little JavaScript game and I've come across the strangest error. This is the code I am using to handle player death (in game):

```
function death(){
    reset();
    clearInterval(loop);
    canvas.level = 1;

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.font = "bold 22px Times New Roman, sans-serif ";
    ctx.fillText("YOU GOT DEAD", canvas.width/2 - 70, canvas.height/2);
    ctx.font = "16px helvetica, sans-serif ";
    ctx.fillText("Game will Restart in 7 Seconds", canvas.width/2 - 100, canvas.height/2 + 30);
    //VVV HERE'S THE PROBLEM VVV
    window.setTimeout(function(){start_game();}, 7000);
}
```

When I use Document.setTimeout() the game resets and correctly displays the death window and text, however the window will just hang.

When I use Window.setTimeout() the game resets correctly, and waits the correct amount of time before calling the start_game() function, however doesn't show any death screen or text.

Simply just setTimeout() will do the same as window.setTimeout().

What the tits is going on? Any and All explinations are needed and greatfully appreciated

EDIT: Added variable declarations below, all global. Theres quite a large amount of code, so I'm reluctant to paste it all, so I've added in the use of 'loop' as the game loop

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var background = new Image();
var loop;

loop = setInterval(function(){
    update();
    handleCollisions();
    draw();
}, 1000/FPS);
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is shorthand for `window.setTimeout()`, as `window` is the global object in the browser and `setTimeout` is a property (method) of `window`. As for why your message is not shown, it's hard to say. Posting more code or a demo may help.

Comment: In your pasted code all of the variables `death()` makes use of are not defined.  It's basically impossible to help as is.

Comment: There's no Document.setTimeout in any standards browser, where's yours coming from? And in case it's another script adding it, why is it messing with Document (note, uppercase first letter)?

Comment: The correct one to use is `window.setTimeout()`, the other problems you're having are unrelated and you might need to post another question to address those.

Comment: Also, unrelated but you can simplify `window.setTimeout(function(){start_game();}, 7000);` to just `window.setTimeout(start_game, 7000);`

Answer (score 0):

`Document.setTimeout` is not a standard function. If you are looking for a delayed function, as it seems that you are, `window.setTimeout` is correct.

All references that do not resolve to the local scope rising to the parent scope and likewise to its parent's parent's scope. The topmost scope is `window` which is why `setTimeout === window.setTimeout` if the function is not declared elsewhere in usable scopes.

Your error is probably not in using the timeout function. I do note that you have references like `ctx` that is not defined in this block. Please post more code for more help.